# In Windows, given a new file "foo.txt", can I recursively search a directory for files matching that filename and replace them with my new file?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, automation

If I have the file `C:\foo.txt`, I want to recursively search `C:\OtherDir` for files matching `foo.txt` and replace them with `C:\foo.txt`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible using the command `for`. What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: A fair question, the problem with given an attempted answer is that I wasn't really sure where to begin exactly :( If it were Linux I'd do something like `find . -iname "foo.txt" -exec cp foo.txt "{}" \;` so I'd guess I would try to follow a similar pattern here. I was a bit under stress yesterday with time but I'll have a look at translating that to Windows.

Comment: I was also thinking of using xargs but I don't believe Windows has an equivalent to that.

Comment: I think I got it. `for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /s/b foo.txt') do copy /Y foo.txt "%A"` It seems to work for me but are there any "gotchas" in this command? Was your solution different?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DOS REPLACE command

REPLACE [d:][path]filename [d:][path][/A][/P][/R][/S][/U][/W]

Purpose: Replaces stored files with files of the same name from a different storage location.

This command replaces files in the target path designation with files of the same name in the source location.  You can use wildcard characters (? and *) to indicate groups of filenames in the source directories. You CANNOT use this command to replace hidden files or system files.

Options

/A - Adds files specified by the source path designation that DO NOT exist on the target path designation. By using this option, you can selectively add files to a directory: a file in the source path designation that has the same name as a file on the target designation will not be affected.  This option cannot be used in combination with the /S option.

/P - Displays a prompt before each file is replaced allowing you to decide on a file-by-file basis whether or not to allow the replacement.

/R - Replaces both read-only and unprotected files on the target directory. Without this option, any attempt to REPLACE a read-only file will result in an error message and the replacement process will terminate.

/S - Acts both on the target directory and all subdirectories within the target directory. You cannot use the /A option together with this option.

/U - Replaces files on the target drive or directory that are older than their counterparts on the source drive.

/W - Waits for you to insert a disk before starting the replacement process.

Examples

replace *.dat a: /u

The "/u" is very important. It means "update" and tells the replace command to only copy those source files which (a) are also found in the destination directory and which (b) are newer than their counterparts in the destination directory.

You can also use replace to copy only those files which do not exist in the destination directory -- that is, only new files. For example:

replace *.dat a: /a

This is interpreted as 'copy to the a: drive all files in the current directory with a ".dat" extension that are not already present in the a: drive.

To maintain an up-to-date back up copy of all files in a given hard disk directory, then, you can use the following pair of replace commands together:

replace c:\india a:\india /u

replace c:\india a:\india /a